# How can I send the program from main to another method?

Tags: c++, methods, program-entry-point, cout

I want to print the output of the `cout` however the code is not working.
Any tips would be helpful.

```
int main()
{
    cout<<"10+20"<<calc(10,20,+);
    cout<<"10*20"<<calc(10,20,*);
    cout<<"10-20"<<calc(10,20,-);
    cout<<"10/20"<<calc(10,20,/);

}

int calc (int a, int b, char c)
{
   int total=0;
   if(c=='+'){
     total = a+b;
   }else if(c=='*'){
     total = a*b;
   }else if(c=='-'){
     total = a-b;
   }else if(c=='/'){
     total = a/b;
   }
   return total;
}
```

Comment: is this a typo? without `'` quote char?

Comment: `+` isn't a `char`, it is an operator. `'+'` is a `char`.

Comment: voting to close as a simple typo

Comment: you need to pass the operators as characters '+' And you need to declare the function before using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operators must be inclosed in single quotes as you are passing them as character arguments.

```
int main()
{  
    cout<<"10+20"<<calc(10,20,'+');
    cout<<"10*20"<<calc(10,20,'*');
    cout<<"10-20"<<calc(10,20,'-');
    cout<<"10/20"<<calc(10,20,'/');
}
```

Comment: Hello, nitpicker here! This is the *definition* of `main`, not the declaration.

Comment: it is not necessary to define the main method after the funtion

Comment: Okay. I will edit it